# sys.argv is different when in interactive mode in Ipython

Tags: ipython, interactive, argv

When I run a script with Ipython in interactive mode, the `sys.argv` argument list is different in the interactive part of the execution than in the script.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

```
oskar@RR06:~$ cat test.py
import sys
print(sys.argv)
temp = sys.argv

oskar@RR06:~$ ipython -i test.py -- foo bar
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
['/home/oskar/test.py', 'foo', 'bar']

In [1]: temp
Out[1]: ['/home/oskar/test.py', 'foo', 'bar']

In [2]: sys.argv
Out[2]: ['/usr/local/bin/ipython', '-i', 'test.py', '--', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

If I just invoke `ipython`, and look at `sys.argv` I get

```
In [3]: sys.argv
Out[3]: ['/usr/bin/ipython3']
```

Your `Out[2]` looks the same - the full list as provided by the shell and Python interpreter.  Remember we are running a Python session with `ipython` import:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# This script was automatically generated by setup.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from IPython import start_ipython
    start_ipython()
/usr/bin/ipython3 (END)
```

But look at `ipython -h`;  in the first paragraph:

> it executes the file and exits, passing the
>       remaining arguments to the script, just as if you had specified the same
>       command with python. You may need to specify `--` before args to be passed
>       to the script, to prevent IPython from attempting to parse them.

So it's explicitly saying that

```
ipython -i test.py -- foo bar
```

becomes (in effect) - or is run as:

```
python test.py foo bar
```

The `ipython` code has a parser (as subclass `argparse`) that handles many different arguments.  But ones it can't handle, or follow `--` are set aside, and put in the `sys.argv` that your `test.py` sees.

But apparently that `sys.argv` is not what is given to the interactive session.

I think you'd get the same effect

```
$ipython
In[0]: %run test.py foo bar
...
```

`%run` saves the current `sys.argv`, and constructs a new one with `sys.argv = [filename] + args`.  Then after running your `test.py` it restores the `sys.argv`.

This is not a bug, and you aren't doing anything wrong - except expecting the two `sys.argv` to be the same.  It appears that in a plain Python shell, the two `sys.argv` are the same (without any of the options that the shell itself uses).